# Router.go() not working in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to use iron:router to navigate among views in my meteor application. 
I am having trouble getting the Router.go() function to work.

I can navigate from one view to another providing the route path in href tags like this :

```
<a href="/" class="btn red delete-subcat">Delete This Subcateogry</a>
```

But i cannot do the same from my JavaScript file

```
Router.go('/')
```

Router.go doesn't seem to work at all.I am getting no errors in the console too ( even if i give wrong template name inside the go() function ). I have no idea where I messed up.

This is my Router configuration :

```
Router.route('dashhome', {
  path: '/',
  layoutTemplate: 'dashboard',
});

Router.route('brands', {
  path: '/brands',
  layoutTemplate: 'dashboard',
});
```

Also I have declared all my routes in a separate js file. I don't know if that could be an issue.

Thanks in advance,
Sanath

Comment: What if you try to run Router.go('/') from your browser console? What happens? Could it be you're not running the code from the correct .js file?

Comment: Add this at the end of your router config: `Router.route('go', function(){ Router.go('/'); });` then in your browser go to /go and see if you get redirected to the dashhome template.  If that works, Router.go is working fine.  Then edit your question and provide more details about where you're making the call from (is it from a helper, an event, somewhere else?).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the route's *name* instead of its *path*?

[According to the iron-router guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#named-routes):

> If you don't give it a name, the router will guess its name based on
>   the path. But you can provide a name explicitly using the name option.

Since you gave an explicit name ("dashhome") to your route, you should use it in `Router.go()` instead of the path:

```
Router.go('dashhome');
```